# Finding factors to an integer using functions in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print factors for a given integer. As output, I should be printing the input number and factors of that number. Instead, i get output of 2.

Where have i made a mistake?

I am new to c++ and any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>

int fact(int x);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout<<"plz,enter no."<<endl;
    cout<<fact(x)<<endl;
}
int fact(int num)
{
    for ( int i = 2; i <= num; ++i )
    {
        while ( num % i == 0 )
        {
            num /= i;
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Format your code. 2. Step through your code in a debugger, watching specifically how `i` and `num` changes while inside the loop.

Comment: Please search on the internet about various ways of debugging a C++ code in the IDE that you are using. If you are not using any, then I assume you are on Linux and look up how to use 'gdb'.

Comment: Please Format my code and help me to get output.

Comment: From first look, you dont set `x` variale, it is uninitialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made your code work. But you can improve this code by running only `sqrt(num)` iterations.

```
#include<iostream>

int fact(int x);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout<<"plz,enter no."<<endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Factors: ";
    fact(x);
}
int fact(int num)
{
    for ( int i = 1; i <= num; ++i )
    {
        if ( num % i == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```